# Showing that $\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Tags: field-theory

I want to show that $\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

well if $p(x)=x^2-3$ then $\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ iff $x^2-3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

How does one show that?

Comment: Of course that $x^3-3\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. It is a polynomial!

Comment: $\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \iff \sqrt{3}$ satisfies an algebraic equation with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ which it obviously does.  What is it you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's recall the definition of algebraic element over a field:

> Let $\mathbb{E}$ an extension of the field $\mathbb{F}$. An element $\alpha \in \mathbb{E}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}$ if there exists a polinomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$.

Now I think probabily you want to say the following:

"$\sqrt{3}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x^2-3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]$ (i.e. is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}$ )"

But this is trivial because $x^2-3$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ and you have $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\Bbb Q \subset \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$.  You have shown that $\sqrt 3$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$, so it must also be over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$